# extra data after last expected column in postgres during csv import

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I am trying to import a CSV file into postgres and getting the following error:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\11\\bin\\psql.exe" --command " "\\copy public.prisons (english_prison_names, dari_prison_names, pashto_prison_names, characters_transmitted) FROM 'C:/Data/prisons.csv' CSV ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';""
```

> ERROR:  extra data after last expected column CONTEXT:  COPY prisons,
>   line 1: "Badakhshan Prison Facility,زن دان ب دخ شان,ب د د خشا هناخ
>   یدنب ن,BKN,,,..."

I have read multiple questions of this kind on stack already and have checked for any extra spaces in the data and I only have 4 columns in my CSV file, 4 columns created in my table.

sample of first few lines of CSV, it seems to be hung up already on the first line?

```
Badakhshan Prison Facility,زن دان ب دخ شان,ب د د خشا هناخ یدنب ن,BKN,,,,,,
Badghis Prison Facility,نز دا ب ن ا د سیغ,ب د ا د ب سیغ ن د ی هناخ,BDG,,,,,,
Baghlan Prison Facility,نز دا ب ن غا ل ن,ب د غا ل ب ن ن د ی هناخ,BGL,,,,,,
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please make it readable for English readers

Comment: S-man, that is the data contained in each cell, not code. its language is irrelevant. thanks for your time tho.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! when i saved to CSV from excel for some reason it added all those extra commas at the end of each line, this led postgres to see them as empty columns, more columns than i prepared.